# Javascript getElementsByClassName() returns undefined,after first time successful execution?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

i am using `var mainDiv=document.getElementsByClassName('amq')[0];` in javascript.

in first time mainDiv has correct value.But after i run again the function returns undefined.

What is the reason for that?

note: i am using chrome browser.

Comment: getElementsByClassName always returns an object, console it and check for the index values.

Comment: if anyone downvote,just give solution before to press that button.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely because the second time you run it there are no elements with class `amq` so the returned collection  or array is empty, there is no 0'th entry so `mainDiv` is undefined.

Comment: @ HBP : thank u.but that class 'amq' is there only,i just refresh the page and check,that time class is there.but returns undefined.thats my problem.

Comment: Try `console.log (document.getElementByClassName ('amq'))` before your `var mainDiv ....` and tell us what it says.